# Substring domainname from URL SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have a set of Data:

```
www.google.com.sg
www.yahoo.com
marketwatch
bing.com
bbc.co.uk
```

Some data has `www.`, some doesn't. Some has `.com`/`.com.sg`/`.com.ul`, some doesn't.

How do I extract just the name e.g. `google`, `yahoo`, `marketwatch`, `bing`, `bbc` using SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MS SQL Server syntax of CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING you could do something like...

(Deliberately overly split-up to mak eeach step obvious.)

```
WITH
  url_start AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN LEFT(myURL, 4) = 'www.' THEN 4 ELSE 1 END AS d_start
  FROM
    myTable
)
,
  url_end
AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN
      CHARINDEX('.', myURL, d_start) = 0
    THEN
      LEN(myURL) + 1
    ELSE
      CHARINDEX('.', myURL, d_start)
    END as d_end
  FROM
    url_start
)
SELECT
  *,
  SUBSTRING(myURL, d_start, d_end - d_start) AS domain
FROM
  url_end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function in SQL to remove the `www.` if it doesn't exist it will leave the string as it is.

```
Select Replace(URLColumn, 'www.','') as [CleanURLColumn]
From YourTable
```

**EDIT**

Sorry I missed out the ending - based on the sample data you have provided this will extract the name:

```
Select  Case
        When CharIndex('.', Replace(URL, 'www.','')) > 0 then
           Left(Replace(URL, 'www.',''), CharIndex('.',Replace(URL, 'www.',''))-1)
        Else
           Replace(URL, 'www.','')
        End as [CleanURL]

From dbo.YourTable
```

Comment: You are way too awesome! Million Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
(
  select replace(URL, 'www.', '')+'.' as url
  from myTable
)
select
  left(url, charindex('.', url)-1)
from cte
```