# Reducing redundancy/duplication in SQL Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, coding-style

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578379/substring-domainname-from-url-sql) on stackoverflow, the accepted answer involves repeating the same code snippets several times.  In my experience, many people strive to reduce that by encapsulating the code snippets in various ways, for various reasons;
- Maintainability (fewer places to change)
- Readability     (read the code once, then it's 'alias' each subsequent time)
- etc, etc

Using the code in the linked question, how would you set out to reduce the repetition of identical code snippets?  Or would you just leave it as-is?

(Not using alternative logic, but sticking to the use of REPLACE, etc, just changing the presentaiton of the same logic.)

```
Select  Case
        When CharIndex('.', Replace(URL, 'www.','')) > 0 then
           Left(Replace(URL, 'www.',''), CharIndex('.',Replace(URL, 'www.',''))-1)
        Else
           Replace(URL, 'www.','')
        End as [CleanURL]
From dbo.YourTable
```

(The accepted answer changed, so I copied the code example to here.)

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, as I think I have caused confusion.

This is not:
- How do I encapsulate this entire piece of code for re-use?

But it is rather:
- How do I reduce rendundancy within this piece of code?

Comment: You could create a SQL function to do the cleanup.

Comment: Within that function the duplication of code still exists.  Thus, to write this logic, in any context, the code contains duplication.  (REPLACE is used identically 4 times, for example.)

Comment: Ahhhh, I now see what you mean. Well i think it is quite readable if you use it in only one Function and highly maintainable. Setting up sql structures which are more difficult to read isn't nice for other programmers having to maintain your code ( if their skills aren't as high as yours )

Comment: This particaular example is quite simple I agree.  I often encounter the same issue in more complicated forms, but thought this was a good simplified example to establish the principle.

Comment: You'd use it in a function, maybe use `IF` rather than a `CASE` statement and use a variable to store the result of the `REPLACE` if you need it on all code paths.

Comment: @chris - that doesn't (in and of itself) address the duplicated uses of REPLACE within the resulting function.  This isn't about encapsulating this piece of code, but rather reducing the redundancy within this piece of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
;with cte as
(
  select replace(URL, 'www.', '')+'.' as url
  from myTable
)
select
  left(url, charindex('.', url)-1)
from cte
```

**Edit 1** You can use a nested select that does the repeated code. Not really any different than using a cte.

```
Select  Case
        When CharIndex('.', URL) > 0 then
           Left(URL, CharIndex('.',URL)-1)
        Else
           URL
        End as [CleanURL]
From 
  (select Replace(URL, 'www.','') as URL
   from myTable) as T
```

**Edit2** Removed the duplicate charindex. Using cross apply

```
select
  case
    when c2.idx > 0 then
      left(c1.url, c2.idx)
    else
      c1.url
  end
from myTable as m
  cross apply (select replace(m.URL, 'www.', '')) as c1(url)
  cross apply (select charindex('.', c1.url)) as c2(idx)
```

Comment: Concatenating '.' to the string is quite a nice trick. It's a tad less readable, though...

Comment: Actually I meant to say that it's more readable but also more difficult to understand.

Comment: I agree that it's a good trick for concise code, but it does kind of skirt around the point of my question. I had hoped to make this a straw poll about reducing repetition in code, not about refactoring the logic itself, the chosen logic is a sample case, not a queswtion itself. As such, the use of the CTE for the REPLACE is relevant to my question, the use of the `+'.'` breaks the "same logic" constraint :( I'm tempted to delete this question as it seems it's point is being completely missed :(

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by UW Concept, but using a table valued function and sub_query to avoid the performance penalties associated with the suggest scalar function and use of an internal variable.

```
SELECT
  myTable.*,
  cleanup.domain
FROM
  myTable
CROSS APPLY
  dbo.CleanupURL(myTable.myURL) as cleanup
```

Using the following function...

```
CREATE FUNCTION
  dbo.CleanupUrl(@urlstring nvarchar(200))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN suffix_pos = 0 THEN
      myURL
    ELSE
      LEFT(myURL, suffix_pos - 1)
    END AS domain
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      myURL,
      CharIndex('.', myURL) AS suffix_pos
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        REPLACE(@urlstring, 'www.', '') as myURL
    )
    AS no_prefix
  )
  AS suffix_found
)
```

Comment: This looks like a neat solution. Even though I don't know the performance cost of a subselect three levels down. I assume it's faster than assigning values to a variable?

Comment: The optimisation engine should be able to unravel it extremely effectively, as if it had no subselects at all. It should behave in the same manner as use of a view, being expanded in-line within any query that uses the function, then compiled quite efficiently.

Comment: I don't understand how you can say which will perform better without testing? Your table valued function has syntax errors, there is no `RETURN` statement or `TABLE` defintion

Comment: I can't categorically state a difference in performance.  But I can be sure of certain mechanisms in play.  The predominant factor I had in mind is that a table valued function can be defined 'inline', that is without any DDL, T-SQL, etc, just a straight query.  One conceptualisation of this is that the optimiser can effectively just 'copy and paste' this code into any query that uses the function, and compile it all from there.  As oposed to using a scalar function that is inherently not Set Based and not optimisable in the same way.

Comment: `RETURN` statement added.  Table definition not required.

Comment: Using `WITH` is more readable and concise, while achieving the same thing. Look at Mikael Eriksson's answer for example.

Comment: @dancek : Vote for that then :)  I'm effectively trying (and failing) to get a straw poll of opinions and options.

Answer (score 0):

[The `WITH` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) should be quite suitable for this:

```
WITH replaced_urls AS (
    SELECT Replace(URL, 'www.','') AS url,
           CharIndex('.', Replace(URL, 'www.','')) AS idx
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
Select  Case
    When idx > 0 then
       Left(url, idx-1)
    Else
       url
    End as [CleanURL]
From replaced_urls
```

This creates a temporary table that exists for the duration of the query, containing the results that are used multiple times. *(I didn't test this, but should work.)*

Comment: I edited my explanations into Mikael Eriksson's answer, which is better than mine. I'll delete this once the edit is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with a function

```
SELECT dbo.CleanupUrl(URL) AS CleanURL FROM yourTable;
```

The function that takes care of the formatting

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CleanupUrl(@urlstring nvarchar(200))
RETURNS nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @SReturn nvarchar(200), @ReplacedURL nvarchar(200)
  SET @ReplacedURL = Replace(@urlstring, 'www.','')
  SELECT @SReturn = Case
        When CharIndex('.', @ReplacedURL) > 0 then
           Left(@ReplacedURL, CharIndex('.',@ReplacedURL)-1)
        Else
           @ReplacedURL
        End

RETURN @SReturn
END
```

You can then call this function from every query .

Comment: Apologies, I meant something else.  I don't mean "how to avoid writing this logic several times", but rather "how to avoid repetition within this one piece of code".  Avoiding the duplicated use of REPLACE, for example, as it is identical in all 4 places.

Comment: I edited my post. It can be done quite easily. This way you only have the replacement once, and store it in a var. I don't think this the **best** performing way. But it is readable, and maintainable.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH
  prefix_removed
AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    REPLACE(URL, 'www.','') AS myURL_NoPrefix
  FROM
    myTable
)
,
  suffix_start
AS
(
   SELECT
     *,
     CharIndex('.', myURL_NoPrefix) AS domain_end
   FROM
     prefix_removed
)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN
    doamin_end = 0
  THEN
    myURL_NoPrefix
  ELSE
    LEFT(myURL_NoPrefix, domain_end-1)
  END AS domain
FROM
  prefix_removed
```

Comment: Your solution seems to allow for the possibility of addresses like `www.nosuffixdomain`, but does nothing about the addresses like `noprefixdomain-www.com`. Which of the two do you think is more likely to come across?

Comment: I really am impressed at just how well you completely failed to understand that the logic itself is not relevant.  Question, comments, edits, all totally ignored.  This is NOT about the logic, the logic is a SAMPLE CASE, the exact behaviour of which is totally irrelevant.

Comment: I'm sorry. Wouldn't say that *all* was ignored, though, still some crucial bits probably were. Sorry again.

Comment: @AndriyM - Necro post - It appears I was a complete ####er back then, I belatedly apologise!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  myTable.*,
  LEFT(noPrefix.myURL, domain_end.pos) AS domain
FROM
  myTable
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT REPLACE(myTable.myURL, 'www.', '') AS myURL) AS [noPrefix]
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT CHARINDEX('.', noPrefix.MyURL) AS pos) AS [suffix_start]
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT CASE WHEN suffix_start.pos = 0 THEN LEN(noPrefix.myURL) ELSE suffix_start.pos - 1 END AS pos) AS [domain_end]
```