# Parse Domain from a given URL in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, url

I fount this answer, but wanted to expand on the question and couldn't find any solutions here on stack or through searching google.

[Substring domainname from URL SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578379/substring-domainname-from-url-sql)

Basically the link above solves my problem with a simple URL like parsing "www.google.com" with the result of google.

What I am looking for to expand on that is the solution from the link above doesn't help with url's like 'www.maps.google.com' that just returns maps.

WHat I would like is to have it return 'google' from the url 'www.maps.google.com' or return 'example' from 'www.test.example.com'.

If anyone has a solution to this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Update: To be more specific I will also need parsing on second level domains etc. 'www.maps.google.com.au' to return 'google'

Here is my Sql function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[parseURL]  (@strURL varchar(1000))
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN

IF CHARINDEX('.', REPLACE(@strURL, 'www.','')) > 0
SELECT @strURL = LEFT(REPLACE(@strURL, 'www.',''), CHARINDEX('.',REPLACE(@strURL,              'www.',''))-1)
Else
SELECT @strURL = REPLACE(@strURL, 'www.','')

RETURN @strURL
END
```

Comment: How would you want to deal with [second level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain), e.g. `www.google.com.sg` or `bbc.co.uk`?

Comment: Yeah I just updated my question to include second level domains. I would also want return 'google' from 'www.google.com.sg'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest this

```
DECLARE @URL nvarchar(max) = 'www.maps.google.com'

DECLARE @X xml = CONVERT(xml,'<root><part>' + REPLACE(@URL, '.','</part><part>') + '</part></root>')

SELECT [Domain] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @X.nodes('/root/part[position() = last() - 1]') T(c)
```

The approach is to convert the URL to XML and then use XPath to find the domain.

**UPDATE**

Regarding second-level domains, I believe the only reliable way it to have them all in a table (top-level domains should probably be in a table too) and then you could use this query:

```
DECLARE @URL nvarchar(max) = 'www.maps.google.com'

DECLARE @X xml = CONVERT(xml,'<root><part>' + REPLACE(REVERSE(@URL), '.','</part><part>') + '</part></root>')

;WITH SplitCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        (SELECT REVERSE(T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(256)')) FROM @X.nodes('/root/part[. = ../part[position() = 1]]') T(c)) AS TLD,
        (SELECT REVERSE(T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(256)')) FROM @X.nodes('/root/part[. = ../part[position() = 2]]') T(c)) AS D2,
        (SELECT REVERSE(T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(256)')) FROM @X.nodes('/root/part[. = ../part[position() = 3]]') T(c)) AS D3
)
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN SLD.Domain IS NULL THEN S.D2 ELSE S.D3
    END AS Domain
FROM
    SplitCTE AS S
    LEFT JOIN TLD ON TLD.Domain = S.TLD
    LEFT JOIN SLD ON SLD.Domain = S.D2
```

The TLD/SLD tables I used for this example are below. The full list of domains is in this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). Be careful to use `NVARCHAR` as some are localized.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TLD
(
    Domain nvarchar(10)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SLD
(
    Domain nvarchar(10)
)
GO

INSERT TLD VALUES ( 'com')
INSERT TLD VALUES ( 'uk')
INSERT SLD VALUES ( 'co')
```

Comment: This is what I had to do. I got all TLD's in one table, then compiled a list of Second level domains and placed that in a table and used your query above. Pain finding a list of second level domains. Thank you for your answer and help on this.

Answer (score 4):

The TLD issue can really slow down your code, and add a maintenance requirement, so I decided to include subdomains.  Here's what I use:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.spExtractDomainFromURL ( @strURL NVARCHAR(1000) )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    --Strip Protocol
    SELECT  @strURL = SUBSTRING(@strURL, CHARINDEX('://', @strURL) + 3, 999)

    -- Strip www subdomain
    IF LEFT(@strURL, 4) = 'www.'
        SELECT  @strURL = SUBSTRING(@strURL, 5, 999)

    -- Strip Path
    IF CHARINDEX('/', @strURL) > 0
        SELECT  @strURL = LEFT(@strURL, CHARINDEX('/', @strURL) - 1)

    RETURN @strURL
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Someone will probably have a better solution but here is what I got:

```
LEFT(RIGHT(@strURL, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@strURL)) +  CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@strURL), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@strURL)) + 1, LEN(@strURL))) - 1), CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@strURL), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@strURL)) + 1, LEN(@strURL))) - 1)
```

I am not the best at string manipulation, so I am sure it is possible to shorten my really long line of code. Basically, I would use the REVERSE function to get the last period and then go from there. My code brings in the characters between the last and second to last commas.

Be aware that using a website such as www.test.co.uk will not work with my solution. I would propose that it is merely a starting point, and you would have to code for outliers.

Comment: That works great for something that has only one extension. What if and I should have been more specific in my question, so say the url is 'www.maps.google.com.au'. Your answer returns 'com'. Other than that, this answer worked great and thank you for your response.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The problem you are going to have is all of the possible outliers. I would recommend something similar to what Serge is suggesting, and put the outliers in a table to be referenced. We as humans can easily identify the data you need, but unfortunately a computer cannot. It really depends on how accurate you need be. Also, as far as scalability goes, I would again suggest trying to understand what Serge is doing in his post. My method is quick and dirty, but if you are needing to add more logic it probably isn't the best route.

Answer (score 3):

What I did here is substring the url after the protocol '://'.

I then take that string and substring all text up to the first forward slash.

You can do it in one line as well, if you need it for a query, or use it in as a scalar function like I would.

Also, it would be a good idea to add some code to check for nulls or just bad strings in general. If you want to keep it as a single line of code, try using the ISNULL and NULLIF functions.

```
DECLARE @urlSansProtocol VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @urlSansProtocol = Substring(@url, CharIndex('://', @url)+3 ,LEN(@url))
RETURN Substring(@urlSansProtocol, 0   ,CharIndex('/',  @urlSansProtocol ))
```

Comment: You should append some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

PARSENAME will split up to four items seperated by the "." mark.  Parsename counts from the right.  If the object_name to parse has more than four parts NULL will be retruned.

```
select PARSENAME ( REPLACE('www.maps.google.com.au', 'www.','')  , 3 ) 
select PARSENAME ( REPLACE('www.maps.google.com', 'www.','')  , 2 )
```

Comment: this works in some instances but not to the level I need it, thank you for your reply though